# 反復子について(unity)

Tags: c#, unity2d

現在、unityにて停止操作を導入しようと以下のコードを入力したのですが以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。改善方法について、もしくはそれを掲載しているサイトについてご教授いただけますと幸いです。
34行目:voidは反復子インターフェイス型ではないため、BlockController.OnTrigger2D[UnityEngine.Collider2D]の本体は反復子ブロックにできません

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlockController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float f=0.3f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    void RightButtonDown(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
            transform.position += new Vector3 (0.32f, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void LeftButtonDown(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            transform.position -= new Vector3 (0.32f, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    void UpButtonDown(){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            Quaternion q=Quaternion.Euler(0,0,90.0f);
            transform.rotation = q * transform.rotation;
        }
    }

    void OnTrigger2D(Collider2D other){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        RightButtonDown ();
        LeftButtonDown ();
        UpButtonDown ();
        if (transform.position.y < -8) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnTrigger2D`ではどのような処理を行いたいのでしょうか？

Comment: OnTrigger2Dないしif OnTrigger2D()以下（おそらくOnTrigger2Dには判定だけ読ませるのがよいのでしょうか？）では他のオブジェクトに接触後、3秒間は入力を受け付けその後、完全に停止する（表示はされている）という処理を行いたいと思っています。

Comment: 重ね重ね申し訳ありません。collision2D otherで操作しているプレハブを数秒間操作後、this.enabled=false;で停止させようとしています。